# What is the best practice about sharing the model for different projects when use domain driven design?

Tags: domain-driven-design

So we may apply the domain driven design for multiple projects but there could be intersection of the same piece of domain model.

In this case, how to apply the domain driven design (use ORM, model first, generating database schema)? Create multiple databases with a lot of same tables? Or how to share data? Use synonyms? What is the possible strategy to resolve the sharing model (including data)?

Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In my previous project we had a lot of discussions regarding having redundant info in several models that have some shared parts.

What we found interesting is that we thought that several projects (not C# proj, but real large development projects) or call it systems very rarely share the exact same perspective on how using the model. We thought that in a larger domain that spans over several application/systems/projects you could spot several core's where you don't want the cores to be duplicated in each application.

It all ended up with a domain that where distributed on several machines. And we had GUID keys to bind them together in database. But since we did this "model first", sub domains looked at each other like infrastructure related services that where reached through Domain events.

Complicated? Not really. Here's an example:
**Domain one (Salary review system)** - We have a Salary Review statistic system which conduct evaluation on employees salary and how they related to their experience, age and performance. The Core is questionnaire form, work evaluation, questionnaire answers, rating. salary modification advices etc.

**Domain two (Employee system)** - Here you manage your employee, register new employees, handle rehab, maybe personal development, salary, employee contract, employee benefits etc.

**Domain three (Performance management)** - Here you handle history of employee experience, goals, achievements, and agreements between boss and employees about personal development, rating and grade of performance.

As you notice the Core of each domain is different but they share some concerns. Depending on deployment, infrastructure and requirement on how tight they should relate/respond to each other - the tech how to solve this could differ.

I Prefer to do this tech independent. We used NServiceBus for synchronizing domain through Domain Events (Udi Dahn's Domain Event Pattern).

For instance, Once we have completed a salary review for an employee and boss should be informed that Joe should get a chance of salary increase with 200 - 500 $ this year.

The method ApplySalaryReview on entity aggregate root Employee do not only save the review result, it also trigger domain event NotifySalaryReviewSubscribers which trigger an eventhandler HandleNotifySalaryReviewSubscribersEvent in Application layer that takes a infrastructure service in ctor. That service puts result in a message queue that all systems that need this info can subscribe on this message. 
In our case, it is Domain two (Employee system). The employee system import result and notify employee's boss that he got new info for the upcoming salary talk with this particular employee.

I hope I may have shread some light on one way of doing it. There are so many other ways as well...

Comment: Please comment or discuss more about this topic. I'm ready... :-) Because this is a common scenario, draw your bounded contexts in your domain.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to (re-)read the strategic design patterns in the [blue book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215).

Comment: You might want to mention which chapter is specific for it

Comment: Well, I think you can only make an informed decision after having read all the related chapters in PART IV (they discuss all the options available to you). It would be kind of presumptuous on my part if I were to tell you which chapter to read based on your 6 lines description.